# Getting JSON value from JSON String using Shell Script

Tags: json, regex, shell, pattern-matching

I have this JSON String:

```
{"name":"http://someUrl/ws/someId","id":"someId"}
```

I just want to get value for "id" key and store it in some variable. I succesfully tried using jq. But due to some constraints, I need to achieve this just by using grep and string matching.

I tried this so far: `grep -Po '"id":.*?[^\\]"';` But that is giving `"id":"ws-4c906698-03a2-49c3-8b3e-dea829c7fdbe"` as output. I just need the id value. Please help

Comment: Use `grep -Po '(?<="id":")[^"]+'`

Comment: there's a reason XML and JSON parsers exist: regular expressions are simply not powerful enough to parse them. You should push back on the constraints and <strike>ask</strike> tell your superiors to let you do your job with the right tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a PCRE regex, you may use lookarounds. Thus, you need to put `"id":"` into the [positive lookbehind construct](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and then match 1 or more chars other than `"`:

```
grep -Po '(?<="id":")[^"]+'
```

where

- `(?<="id":")` - requires a `"id":"` to appear immediately to the left of the current position (but the matched text is not added to the match value) and
- `[^"]+` - matches and adds to the match 1 or more chars other than `"`.

To get the values with escaped quotes:

```
grep -Po '(?<="id":")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*'
```

Here, `(?<="id":")` will still match the position right after `"id":"` and then the following will get matched:

- `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more consequent sequences of:

  - `\\.` - a `\` and any char (any escape sequence)
  - `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`

Comment: `curl -X POST -d '{"asin":"\"$1\"", "template":"bolt","version":"1d"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://someUrl`

Hi Asin i want to get as command line? This is not substituting the asin value. Any idea on this?

Comment: So there can be escaped quotes, right? I added an alternative solution supporting escape sequences.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Can you please help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758557/passed-command-line-argument-in-double-quotes-to-curl ?

Answer (score 1):

See [`Jshon`](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/), it is a command line Json parser for shell script usage.

```
echo '{"name":"http://someUrl/ws/someId","id":"someId"}' | jshon -e id
"someId"
```

Just noticed I read past the section stating you needed to use standard tools available, if your admin doesn't allow Jshon it is very likely that the system will have `Python` available which you could use.

```
echo '{"name":"http://someUrl/ws/someId","id":"someId"}' | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["id"]'
someId
```

Using grep for this is just asking for trouble, I would avoid it and opt for a proper Json parser as above.