# Passed command line argument in double quotes to curl

Tags: shell, curl

My script is taking the command line argument and it needs to pass this to curl command in double quotes. This is the simplified version of what I tried so far:

```
json=$1;
echo $json;
```

`curl -X POST -d '{"asin":\"$json\", "template":"bolt","version":"1d"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://someURL`

But its not working. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using curl POST with variables defined in bash script functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029902/using-curl-post-with-variables-defined-in-bash-script-functions)

Answer (score 2):

$-variables in single quoted strings don't get expanded. The `-d` argument needs be in double quotes, or at least the `$json` part needs to be:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"asin":"'"$json"'", "template":"bolt","version":"1d"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://someURL
```

'-terminates the single-quoted string, then `"$json"` follows, and then `'` starts an adjacent single quoted string.

The `"$json"` variable shouldn't expand to a string containing unescaped double quotes or the resulting json will be broken.